# Net Core Migrate Projects to 3.1: Should we Upgrade Common/Shared Project First?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

We are about to upgrade our .Net Core solutions. We have multiple Microservices, like:

1. Customer
2. Billing
3. Accounts
4. Inventory
5. Marketing

All of them are relying on the **Common Utilities Project**. It contains great tools like:

- File parsers,
- Extension methods,
- Common functions/methods
- etc.

which are used all across the company.

---

When we want to upgrade from 2.2 to 3.1 which should be first project?

I'm wondering what if all our 2.2 Microservices are pointing to 3.1 Utilities Project?!

a) Are these projects forward compatible?

b) What if the new (3.1) Common project is not upgraded properly, that's why all other solutions can face errors?

c) My proposition is start with upgrading all 5 Microservices to 3.1 and finally upgrade the Common Solution to 3.1. Is this an optimal solution?

I'm trying to read through [Upgrade guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Maybe update your packages first? In general, there is no right answer here. It's up to you to decide what is your upgrade strategy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the common projects are published to an internal nuget feed.
You can create a new version of a common project which targets .net core 3.1 and 2.2 by using target frameworks in your .csproj

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.2;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
```

Then you can update each service individual.

If everything is in the same solution and you are using project references, you are not really doing micro services and I would suggest putting the common code in different solutions and publish them to an internal nuget feed.

When we did our upgrade, we first upgrade our common package. We then chose a simple service to upgrade to .net core 3.1 and upgrade all of it's dependencies through nuget, including our common package.

We had some issues with custom swashbuckle code in the first upgrade, but after we did one service, the others where smooth sailing.

The key is to use nuget for all your dependecies, also the ones you wrote yourself in a shared library.

We updated the common package first because it doesn't impact any service if the new version is not used. You only impact a service when you update the version of the common package in the micro service.

You can setup Common by setting up correct branches / pre release tags of your nuget packages and have a clear version strategy for your packages.

Comment: See the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-target-frameworks

Comment: We updated the common package first because it doesn't impact any service if the new version is not used. You only impact a service when you update the version of the common package in the micro service. Is your common package a PackageReferences or a ProjectReference in your csproj file?

Comment: ok, we have nugets for everything, so once we upgrade Common to 3.1 and then add new methods to, the 2.2 projects cannot use anymore additions of methods ?

Comment: You can by setting up the correct branches / pre release tags of your nuget packages and have a clear version strategy for your packages.

Comment: I concur with @PrebenHuybrechts’ strategy. This is the same approach I’ve used on several large projects. It’s also worth noting that with the exception of any ASP.NET-related utilities, I’d expect your shared class libraries to have the fewest number of breaking changes—if there are any at all. Most of the challenges I‘ve encountered in upgrades have related to in-depth customizations of the MVC tooling. Most everything else continued to work.

Comment: hi Preben, by the way, I asked team to place the two references for 2.2 and 3.1,they stated "if we will follow the directive mechanism how will we handle the Nuget packages for both versions? I think we should forget about .NET core 2.2 as it has reached the end of life and we should spend time upgrading to .Net core 3.1 (before the next wave of .Net 5)

Comment: Nugget handles this for you, it wil package both targets, the correct one will be chosen when installing or updating the package.

Answer (score 0):

If the common packages are only tools, I would highly advise you to convert them first into .Net Standard, this way they can be usable by all .Net Core versions as well as any old framework you might have.